# HTML how to play an embed video on loop with a start and end time in the video

Tags: html, css, loops, video, embed

i would like a video to play with a start and end and loop that specific part is it possible? im still learning basic html so not nothing javascript knowledge yet

Say i would like the video to play from start = 0 and end = 164
this is what i got so far, but when the video loops it plays past my end than restarts

```
<div class="video-background">
     <div class="video-foreground">
         <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/q4AoVUamhxo?controls=0&showinfo=0&loop=1&autoplay=1&&autoplay=1&mute=1&rel=0&playlist=q4AoVUamhxo&start=0&end=164" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [YouTube IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). You can check their page for the documentation. I would prefer not to mention each and every detail as you mentioned it as **homework**. If you need help, just comment below this answer and I'll update it with more hints and details

Comment: the video background is stuff we have not covered yet so its an extra i want to put in on my own. The requirements that we already covered and are essential for this homework is already done :) but i understand i will check the page thanks

Comment: We are nowhere near java script features so i wonder is there an easier way?